# platform independent password protection

Tags: platform

I have some folders in an external hard drive which i want password protected. i use the hard drive in windows, mac and linux. Is there a way to do this ? platform independent password protection ? i tried zipping it with password, but the folder is too heavy for zip, i tried that in default zip utility that comes with mac.

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the file system type? NTFS?

Comment: no fat32, i guess i can always format the drive in a ntfs mode !

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution will be to use an encryption software such as [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) to create an encrypted volume, then put the folder you want to protect inside that volume.

This way, you will be able to work with your files as normal (once you've mounted the encrypted volume), and you'll know your files are cryptographically protected.